# How to decode base64 file as a CLI command input?

Tags: shell, command-line, base64, command-line-interface

I have a b64 file, let's call it /home/base.txt

I am trying to run command in CLI, `/command -arg /home/base.txt | base64 -d` but can't seem to find the right syntax to do what I'm trying to do

I can't edit the file to not be in b64, or the command to accept b64. Any help ?

Comment: `can't seem to find the right syntax to do what I'm trying to do` What you are trying to do? `How to decode base64 file as a CLI command input?` I do not understand, so you have a file, which contains data. These data contain another data in base64 encoding. How this all is related to "CLI command input"? How is "decoding" related to "CLI command"?

Comment: Decode b64 file inline as part of a command, as the title suggests

Comment: Not sure what other way to explain it. Again, there is an encoded file, that needs to be decoded and piped as an argument for another command. Trying to do this all together

Comment: `base64 -d encoded.txt | command`

Comment: if arg takes string: `/command -arg "$(base64 -d /home/base.txt)"`

Comment: if arg takes filename: `/command -arg <($base64 -d /home/base.txt)` (needs bash)